# symmetricds with in-memory hsqldb

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, hsqldb, symmetricds

So, i'm trying to migrate mysql db to hsqldb in memory. I'm using symmetricds for this. I've started the symmetricds as a service connected to mysql with following properties:

```
engine.name=corp-000
db.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/corp?tinyInt1isBit=false
db.user=root
db.password=
registration.url=
sync.url=http://localhost:31415/sync/corp-000
group.id=corp
external.id=000
job.purge.period.time.ms=7200000
job.routing.period.time.ms=5000
job.push.period.time.ms=10000
job.pull.period.time.ms=10000
initial.load.create.first=true
auto.registration=true
auto.reload=true
```

Created and loaded all the sym tables with the required data.

Next i created a clientnode through java using ClientSymmetricEngine. This is my java code:

```
public ClientNode(File file) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
  propFile = file;
  Properties propertiesFile = new Properties();
  propertiesFile.load(new FileReader(propFile));
  cEngine = new ClientSymmetricEngine(propertiesFile, true);
  //getcEngine().openRegistration("store", "001");// client is the name of the node group and 001 is the ID
  getcEngine().setup();
  getcEngine().start();
  }    
public ClientSymmetricEngine getcEngine() {
  return cEngine;
}
```

This is the clientNode property file:

```
engine.name=store-001
db.driver=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
db.url=jdbc:hsqldb:mem:store001
db.user=sa
db.password=
registration.url=http://localhost:31415/sync/corp-000
group.id=store
external.id=001
job.routing.period.time.ms=5000
job.push.period.time.ms=10000
job.pull.period.time.ms=10000
```

Following is my code to startup the clientNode and fetch data from the replicated table running on the same JVM:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
  try {             
    new ClientNode(new File("C:/Train/src/main/resources/store-001.properties"));
    Thread.currentThread();
    Thread.sleep(40000);
    Class.forName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:mem:store001;create=false", "sa", "");
    System.out.println("Connection created successfully");
    stmt = con.createStatement();    
    rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT item_id, name FROM item");
    while (rs.next()) {
      System.out.println(rs.getInt("item_id") + " | " + rs.getString("name"));
    }               
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.out);
  }
}
```

[image]

**When i run the main(), i see that symmetricds does the replication from mysql to hsql. But when i try to fetch the same data from hsql, i get the table object not found exception.**

```
java.sql.SQLException: user lacks privilege or object not found: ITEM
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
at hsqlDB.FetchData.<init>(FetchData.java:24)
at hsqlDB.ConnectDatabase.main(ConnectDatabase.java:15)
```

Attaching the full stacktrace.

I would appreciate it if someone could tell me what i'm doing wrong here.

Comment: @Boris: if u look at my question again you will notice that i'm  using in-memory hsqldb and not file-based hsqldb. And yes my urls and syntax are all correct. Is there any other reason that this might happen? Do take a look and let me know

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the statement it uses to create the table, the table name and column names are quoted, which makes them case sensitive.  Change your SQL query to use the same case and quoting, like this:

```
rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT \"item_id\", \"name\" FROM \"item\"");
```